# $ACC^{0}$ vs Poly-size circuits of bounded degree

Tags: complexity-theory, time-complexity, complexity-classes, circuits

We know that NEXP $\not\subset ACC^0$ **(Ryan Williams'10 Result)**. Also, We know that even $\Sigma_{2}^{P}$ cannot have polynomial circuits of bounded degree i.e. $SIZE(n^k)$ for some $k \in N$ **(Kannan's Result)**. Does this give a hint towards $ACC^0$ is far more powerful than polynomial circuits of bounded degree? Are they even comparable?

Comment: It just means lower bounds are very hard to prove. According to wiki, $ACC^0$ is conjectured not to contain majority, which has bounded degree circuits.

Comment: @Complexity No. By polynomial circuits of bounded degree, I mean $SIZE(n^k)$ for a fixed $k$. It is known that $\Sigma_2^{P}$ can't have poly-circuits of bounded degree, Though it is still open if any class lower than $MA_{EXP}$ is in $\cup_{k>0} SIZE(n^k)$ or not.

Comment: @Ariel Yes. $ACC^0$ is conjectured to be strict subset of $TC^0$. But, my question is a bit different. I want to know the relationship between $ACC^0$ and $SIZE(n^k)$ for any fixed $k$. Which is bigger? Some researchers are trying to prove lower bounds in $ACC^0$, $TC^0$, $NC^1$ etc. while some have already established very good lower bounds for $SIZE(n^k)$ for any fixed $k$. What is the connection between these two? Am I missing something?

Comment: @Ariel For example: it is known that Even $Promise-MA$ class can't have circuits of $SIZE(n^k)$ for any fixed $k$ (Result by Rahul Santhanam), whereas the lower bounds with respect to $ACC^0$ is still stuck at NEXP.

Comment: Majority is in $SIZE(n)$ or something like that. This was an example against "$ACC_0$ is much more powerful then $SIZE(n^k)$".

Comment: @Ariel I tried searching it. But no luck. Can you point me to a reference which says this? This would mean that $ACC^0 \subseteq TC^0 \subseteq SIZE(n)$. So, It would make sense that progress on NEXP is stuck on $ACC^0$ and it is still possible that NEXP can be solved through linear sized circuits. Also, you can add the referenced paper as answer. Thank you.

Comment: It does not necessarily mean $ACC^0\subseteq SIZE(n)$. Don't forget that $ACC^0$ has access to unbounded degree many gates. As for a reference, just build a Turing machine to compute majority (count the number of ones and compare it to $n/2$, this takes linear time), and transform it into a circuit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/69222/discussion-between-pawan-kumar-and-ariel).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$ACC^0$ and $SIZE(n^k)$ are probably incomparable for all $k$.

$ACC^0$ is conjectured not to contain $Maj(x_1,..,x_n)$, which has linear size circuits (think about the naive Turing machine for majority and transform it into a circuit, things are much easier when you don't have a depth restriction). This shows that it probably holds that $SIZE(n)\not\subseteq ACC^0$.

On the other hand, $ACC^0$ does allow you to use polynomially many gates (with no degree restriction). We will show that under a certain assumption, for every $k\in\mathbb{N}$ it holds that $ACC^0\not\subseteq SIZE(n^k)$. Consider the problem of deciding whether a graph contains a $c$-size clique (where $c$ is a constant independent of the input).

This problem is obviously in $AC^0$ (for all $c\in\mathbb{N}$), since you can, in the first level, link all subsets of $c$ vertices into AND gates to check whether they form a clique, and in the second level link all the results from the previous level into an OR gate.

If this can be done using $SIZE(n^k)$ circuits, then $\mathsf{NP\subseteq P/Poly}$, since we can construct polynomial size circuits for CLIQUE. The circuit for $n$ vertices graph needs to be able to check the existence of an $1,2,...,n$ clique. Since finding $c$-cliques is in $AC^0$ for all $c$, and we assumed $AC^0\subseteq SIZE(n^k)$, we have an $n^k$ size circuit for each possible clique size, combining those will result in an $n^{k+1}$ size circuit for clique on $n$ vertices graphs, which puts $\mathsf{NP}$ in $\mathsf{P/Poly}$.